# How can I add CORS middleware to routes defined in custom Laravel Nova tool?

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

I'm building a headless cms using laravel nova and vuejs.

I'm having an issue with trying to register the excellent CORS middleware from https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors. I can get this working from the main app but I would like to add this as a dependency to my custom nova tool.

I just can't figure out how to do this.

I've tried adding the middleware in the routes function generated by the `artisan nova:tool` command.

```
/**
 * Register the tool's routes.
 *
 * @return void
 */
protected function routes()
{
    if ($this->app->routesAreCached()) {
        return;
    }

    Route::middleware(\Barryvdh\Cors\HandleCors::class)
       ->prefix('api/meta-blog')
       ->group(__DIR__.'/../routes/api.php');
}
```

But I get an error `Class Barryvdh\Cors\HandleCors does not exist` from `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php` when I hit any of the api paths.

I think this is because the middleware is not registered with the main app. I'm looking to find out how to make this 3rd party nova tool dependency work with the main laravel routing system.

I have successfully used other 3rd party packages with success. But not this one. I can confirm that the package exists and has been loaded in my custom tools autoload file.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this.

In the boot function we can push a middleware to the api group.

```
/**
 * Bootstrap any application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function boot()
{
    ...

    $router = $this->app['router'];
    $router->pushMiddlewareToGroup('api', Barryvdh\Cors\HandleCors::class);
}
```

Then in the routes function

```
/**
 * Register the tool's routes.
 *
 * @return void
 */
protected function routes()
{
    if ($this->app->routesAreCached()) {
        return;
    }

    Route::prefix('api/meta-blog')
        ->group(__DIR__.'/../routes/api.php');
}
```

Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: Thanks a lot bro this was really useful